# How to force sequential execution for asynchronously called functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

I'm new to the idea of asynchronous code, and am still trying to wrap my brain around how everything works.

I'm building a Node Express application which will interface with a database. When running in a development environment I want it to interface with a Sqlite database. (The production database will not use Sqlite. This only applies to creating a small development environment.)

My problem is I'm having trouble controlling the execution order and timing of queries to the database.

I would like to build my SqliteDatabase.js file such that it can only execute queries sequentially, despite the fact that functions in this file will be called by other parts of the program that are running asynchronously.

How can I acheive this?

For reference, here is how I currently have my SqliteDatabase.js file set up:

```
var debug = require('debug')('app:DATABASE');
var sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();

open = function() {
    var db = new sqlite.Database('./test-database.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            debug("We've encountered an error opening the sqlite database.");
            debug(err);
        } else {
            debug("Sqlite database opened successfully.");
        }
    });
    return db;
}

executeSQLUpdate = function(sql, next) {
    var db = open();
    db.serialize(function() {
        console.log("executing " + sql);
        db.run(sql);
        db.close();
        next();
    });
}

exports.executeSQLUpdate = executeSQLUpdate;
```

Is there some way to build a queue, and make it so when the "executeSQLUpdate" function is called, the request is added to a queue, and is not started until all previous requests have been completed?

To give an example, take a look at this code which utilises my SqliteDatabase.js file:

```
ar database = require('../../bin/data_access/SqliteDatabase.js');

var createTestTableStmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(\n" +
    "Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n" +
    "Age INT NOT NULL,\n" +
    "Gender TEXT NOT NULL\n" +
    ");";

var clearTestTableStmt = "DELETE FROM Test;";

var testInsertStmt = "INSERT INTO Test (Name, Age, Gender)\n" +
    "VALUES (\"Connor\", 23, \"Male\");";

createTable = function() {
    database.executeSQLUpdate(createTestTableStmt, clearTable);
}

clearTable = function() {
    database.executeSQLUpdate(clearTestTableStmt, insertRow);
}

insertRow = function() {
    database.executeSQLUpdate(testInsertStmt, function() {
        console.log("Done!");
    });
}

createTable();
```

9 times out of 10 the above code works fine, but every once in a while, the "insert row" function is called before the "clearTable" function is called, which throws an error because of a violated database constraint.

How can I change my implementation of the SqliteDatabase.js file to avoid this issue?

Comment: It looks like the `insertRow` function is ONLY being triggered as a callback in the `executeSQLUpdate` function. If this is correct, there is no way events could be sequencing themselves incorrectly. I expect the problem might be that the function `createTable` being being triggered multiple times. Is there anywhere else is the code that executes either of those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized why the callback function `next()` was sometimes being called before `db.run(sql)`

It turns out that `db.run()` is itself an asychronous function. I updated my code, and added a callback to the `db.run()` line to make sure we don't skip ahead until it's done.

Here's what it looks like now:

```
executeSQLUpdate = function(sql, next) {
    var db = open();
    db.run(sql, function(err) {
        db.close(function() {
            if (next) next(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Nesting each asynchronous function in the previous function's callback, makes each function execute in order.

Thanks to everyone who gave me hints that helped me figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to do this using `await`.  This code will wait for each asynchronous database call to complete before executing the next line.

```
async function createTable() {

  await database.executeSQLUpdate(createTestTableStmt);
  await database.executeSQLUpdate(clearTestTableStmt);
  await database.executeSQLUpdate(testInsertStmt);

  console.log("Done!");

}
```

Your `console.log` statement will only execute once all three have completed.

I should also mention that you need a `try...catch` block around the three database calls to trap any errors and provide an alternate exit point if something should go wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the use of callbacks acheive this as well? I thought "next" would not be called until it was done executing a SQL statement.

Comment: It could, but nesting callbacks gets messy in a big hurry.